# We can’t find an active version of the login flow. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator

Tags: error

need help to fix this error "We can’t find an active version of the login flow. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator. "thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it slightly differently than @satya, but followed the same general pattern.  Since it was so annoying, I'm hoping this post will help someone with the same issue.

First, I could not use workbench, because it required a login, and that login takes me to the same "We can’t find an active version of the login flow" page.

I used visual studio code (which was already set up for development in Salesforce).  From the command palette I chose "Set a default org" and set it to my org I was trying to log in as.  Then, from the command palette, I chose "Open default org".

Comment: Whew man you saved me. I had my flow inactive but the login flow was still there so I thought I was locked out. Your steps got me in so I could delete the login flow. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

u can do it from workbench r u can fix using using eclipse,open eclipse,if u r already using it,right click on any page or class ,click on force.com,then select show in salesforce web.

Answer (score 0):

To activate the flow you need to go to Setup>Create>Workflow & Approvals>Flows 
That will give you a list of flows and will enable activation of a login flow that has been created and setup for the users.

To see which login flow has been set for users go to Setup>Administer>Security Controls>Login Flows - from there you can see the Login Flows set for any profiles and change or delete these if not required. If the flow is still required check if there is an active version using the steps above.

Comment: iam not able to see setup

Comment: sir see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Satya's recommendation works. I have a Windows 10 PC.

1. I downloaded 32-bit Eclipse from here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/neon/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers.
2. I followed these Salesforce instructions to install Force.com IDE in Eclipse:
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm
3. Then performed the steps that Satya recommended. I right-clicked on a trigger, selected 'show in Salesforce Web,' and BOOOM!

Hope this helps someone.